# Error on Deployment Django App with Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I know there is already a Topic of Desployment on Heroku with Django but it didn´t help me.

I have following error:

```
 !     Error while running '$ python markb/manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.

   See traceback above for details.

   You may need to update application code to resolve this error.

   Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:

      $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1

   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

!     Push failed

Answer (score 0):

Disable collectstatic using below command:

```
set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

And then try.

Comment: where should i paste this command?

Comment: when you get this error that time you have to run this command